# Customize label on x axis nvd3 line chart angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I need to format my x Axis with a time format like hour:minutes but the label of it needs to be more complete with year/month/day hour:minutes:seconds

is there a way to do this? I use the option tickFormat for my xAxis but it shows on my x Axis and label the same info...

How to do this? I read something about "tickValues" but can't figure this out.

My code:

```
var rangeSelector = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]; //1h 24h 1w custom



controllerScope.statusViewChartOptions = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'lineChart',
                    height: 600,
                    staggerLabels: true,
                    margin: {
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 70,
                        left: 30
                    },
                    forceY: [0],
                    x: function (d) {
                        return d.x;
                    },
                    y: function (d) {
                        return d.y;
                    },
                    useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                    duration: 500,
                    noData: 'No data to show in the specified range',
                    xAxis: {
                        axisLabel: 'Hours',
                        axisLabelDistance: 20,
                        showMaxMin: false,
                        tickFormat: function (d) {
                            if(rangeSelector.value == "1h"){
                                return d3.time.format("%H:%M")(new Date(d));
                            } else if(rangeSelector.value == "24h"){
                                return d3.time.format("%H:%M")(new Date(d));
                            } else if(rangeSelector.value == "1w"){
                                return d3.time.format("%d-%m")(new Date(d));
                            } else if(rangeSelector.value=="custom"){                   
                                return d3.time.format("%d %b")(new Date(d));
                            }
                        },
                        rotateLabels: -45
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        showMaxMin: false,
                        tickFormat: function (d) {
                            return d3.format('d')(d);
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        enable: true,
                        text: 'Status'
                    },
                    dispatch: {
                        stateChange: function (e) {
                            console.log("stateChange");
                            $scope.api.refresh();
                        },
                        changeState: function (e) {
                            console.log("changeState");
                            $scope.api.refresh();
                        },
                        tooltipShow: function (e) {
                            console.log("tooltipShow");
                            $scope.api.refresh();
                        },
                        tooltipHide: function (e) {
                            console.log("tooltipHide");
                            $scope.api.refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
tooltip: {
                keyFormatter: function(d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%x %X')(new Date(d));
                }
            },
```

Plunker forked from the example in angular NVD3 Github page: http://plnkr.co/edit/77dOGGKEWJljuvSFPMon?p=preview

The D3 Date/Time formats can be found here:
https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#timeFormat

Comment: This works when I have only one line.. I have two lines and cant figure a way to create this for both cases... understand?

Comment: Do you mean you have a cumulative chart with multiple graphs? Could you share the code? The example you gave above shows a single line chart.

Comment: I have a line chart with two lines, one for online and the other for offline

Comment: And I tried your code and nothing happens.. Stills present my chart with tooltip according to xAxis label

Comment: Please create a plunker to show what you are trying to do .

Comment: Glad to know you were able to solve it. Please upvote if you feel my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
tooltip: {
                        contentGenerator: function (e) {
                            //create html
                            var html = "";                  
                            console.log(e.point.x);
                            console.log(e.series[0].key);
                            console.log(e.point.y);
                            var html ="<table><thead><tr><td colspan='3'><strong class='x-value'>"+d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')(new Date(e.point.x))+"</strong></td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: rgb(46, 204, 113);'></div></td><td class='key'>"+e.series[0].key+"</td><td class='value'>"+e.point.y+"</td></tr></tbody></table>"; 
                            return html;
                        },
                        hideDelay: 10
                    },
```